# What will be the upper bound of covering number of $r B_{n}^2$

Tags: banach-spaces, packing-problem

I am very curious to know The covering numbers of the r-radius Euclidean ball $B_{n}^2$  for any $r$ > 0: so
$r B_{n}^2$ is a Euclidean ball with radius $r$

[Have read this but unable to find.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356310/covering-number-of-l-2-ball-in-mathbbrd)

Can anyone kindly tell What will be the upper bound for this case.

Answer (score 2):

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a totally bounded set and let $B$ denote the unit ball. Then,
$$\Big(\frac{1}{\delta} \Big)^n \frac{vol(X)}{vol(B)} \leq N(\delta; X, ||\cdot ||) \leq \frac{vol(X + \frac{\delta}{2} B)}{vol(\frac{\delta}{2} B)}$$

***Proof:*** Let's begin by considering the $\delta-$covering of minimal size, i.e. $\{x_1,...,x_{N(\delta)}\}$, where $N(\delta)$ denotes the $\delta-$covering number. Then,
$$X \subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{N(\delta)} B(x_i, \delta) \implies vol(X) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{N(\delta)} vol(B(x_i,\delta)) = N(\delta) \delta^n vol(B)$$

Thus proving the first inequality. For the upper bound, let $\{x_1,...,x_{M(\delta)}\}$ be the $\delta-$packing of $X$, where $M(\delta)$ denotes the $\delta-$packing number. Then, we have that
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{M(\delta)} B(x_i, \delta/2) \subset X + \frac{\delta}{2} B,$$
where the RHS of the inclusion is a Minkowski sum. This way we conclude that
$$vol(X + \frac{\delta}{2} B) \geq \sum_{i=1}^{M(\delta)} vol(B(x_i,\delta/2)) = M(\delta) vol\Big(\frac{\delta}{2}B\Big),$$
and the upper bound follows from the fact that $N(\delta) \leq M(\delta)$.

Now for the specific case of a ball with radius $r$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$N(\delta; B(r),||\cdot||_2) \leq \frac{vol(rB + \frac{\delta}{2} B)}{vol(\frac{\delta}{2}B)} = \frac{(r + \delta/2)^n vol(B)}{(\delta/2)^n vol(B)} = \Big( 1 + \frac{2r}{\delta}\Big)^n$$
This probably works xD